# WSO2 InResponseTo is missing from saml2p:Response

Tags: wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

We are configuring a new system into our WSO2 Identity Management v5.0.0 server and I see that the InResponseTo token is missing from the saml2p:Response.

Is this a configuration issue?

Thanks,
...pat

Comment: A little more information / configuration please.

Comment: Thanks for asking, this SP has -Custom Claim dialect with 7 defined claims
Inbound Authentication Configuration / SAML2 Web SSO Configuration with Enable Response Signing, Enabled Assertion Signing, Enable Attribute Profile, Include Attributew in the Rsponse Alwasys, and Enable IdP Initiated SSO/SLO checked.

Comment: when using IDP-init-SSO: that doesn't have an InResponseTo

Comment: Thanks, switching off Enable IdP Initiated SSO/SLO appears to have solved the problem.